# server-side caching strategy for user filtered results

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a situation at [www.zipstory.com](http://www.zipstory.com) (beta) where I have n-permutations of feeds coming from the same database. For example, someone can get a feed for whatever city they are interested in and as many of these cities all together so its all sorted by most recent or most votes.

How should I cache things for each user without completely maxing out the available memory when there are thousands of users at the same time?

My only guess is don't. I could come up with a client-side caching strategy where I sort out the cities results but this way I could still cache in a one-size fits all strategy by city.

What approaches do you suggest? I'm in unfamiliar ground at this point and could use a good strategy. I noticed this website does not do that but Facebook does. They must be pulling from a pool of cached user-feeds and plucking them in client-side. Not sure, again I'm not smart enough to figure this out just yet.

In other words...

Each city has its own feed. Each user has an n-permutation of city feeds combined.

I would like to see possible solutions to this problem using c# and ASP.NET

---

Adding to this Febuary 28th, 2013. Here's what I did based on your comments so THANKS!...

- For every user logging in, I cache their preferred city list
- The top 10 post results are cached per city and stored in a Linq based object
- When a user comes in and has x cities as feeds, I go through their city list loop then check if city postings are in cache, if not, I get from DB then populate the individual posting's html into cache along with other sorting elements.
- I recombine the list of cities into one feed for the user and since i have some sorting elements on the linq object, i can resort them in the proper order and give back to the user

This does mean there is some CPU work everytime regardless as I have to combine city lists into a single city list but this avoids going to the database every time and everyone benefits in faster page response times. The main drawback is since I'm not doing a single query UNION on cities before, this requires a single query per city if each was not cached but each city is checked if cached or not individually so 10 queries per 10 cities would only happen if the site is a dead zone.

Comment: Not sure I understand. But shouldn't you cache not for each developer but for each 'filter'? If two users have same 'filter' they share cache. Sth like OutputCache(VaryByParam = filter)

Comment: sorry not trying to confuse. Each user has their own feed permutations of cities. Each city has its own feed.

Comment: @dash colorful commentary sometimes is appropriate and can add an entertainment value to an otherwise dry forum provided it was tastefully done. I don't see a reason to remove it otherwise.

Comment: @zipstory.com I agree - I am new to being an editor however, so I'm learning the ropes :-) I'll think about your feedback.

Comment: @dash, but you did exactly what is supposed to be one so not putting down your efforts, just commenting.

Comment: Are the users permanently online and receiving feeds for all cities they are subscribed to? If not, how do you predict what feeds will be required? That will determine what you put in your read-ahead cache

Comment: @MiserableVariable I'm not sure what you mean by "permanently online". I don't think that is possible right? Think Facebook and your friends for a better analogy since you have feeds to your friends' posts.

Comment: I was suggesting that the caching strategy will depend on the strategy for determining which feeds are required. Does that make sense? Not sure if I am explaining myself properly

Comment: @MiserableVariable I'm not quite sure of this myself. I'm thinking to just cache each cities' top 20 posts and then cache the users' city list, then do the user feeds on the fly as a tradeoff. It will be pulling from cache and then doing the sort logic so it will be more CPU involved but will avoid having to cache specific feeds per user. This isn't the easiest problem for my brain but trivial for others seems.

Comment: I have made the mistake in past of caching data without knowing what will be required. Consider for example you continously refreshing some obscure cities top posts and a single user subscribed to it logging in once a week to check all available posts. At the minimum build some cache hit/miss statistics to know how effective the caching is

Comment: Right. In this case the query model would be an abstraction layer where the actual city data would not have to exist but would exist when used, such as if null then define in cache then always get from cache so cities won't be in some static memory list, only in cache when needed. I think you all are helping me here as this is starting to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judge the situation based on critical chain points.

**If the memory is not a problem**, consider having the whole feed cached and retrieving items from there. For this you can use distributed cache solutions. Some of them are even free. Start from the memcached, http://memcached.org/ . People refer to this approach as *Load Ahead*.

**Sometimes memory *is* a problem** if you want to use asp.net cache with expiration and priorities. In such a case, cache can be gone at any point when the memory becomes a problem. Thus, you load the data again on demand (called as *Load Through*) that affects bandwidth. In such a case, your code should be smarter to get along. If this is an option for you, then try to cache as little as possible. e.g. cache loaded items each and when the user requests a feed, check if all items are present in the cache. If not, you will have to fetch either all or missing ones again. I have done something similar in the past, but cannot provide the code. Key point is: cache entities and then cache feeds with references (IDs) to the entities. Thus, when a particular feed is requested, you check that all references are still valid in the cache. BTW, asp.net provides cache dependencies for such scenarios, so read about that too, - may be helpful.

In any case, have *Decorator* design pattern in mind when implementing data access layer, that would allow you to: 1 - postpone the caching concerns for the later development phases, and 2 - switch between the two approaches described above depending on how things go. I would start with simpler (and cheaper) built-in solution, and then would switch to the distributed cache solutions when really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Only cache the minimal amount of different information per user that you need.

For example, if it fits in memory, cache the complete set of feeds and only store, per user, the id's of the feeds they are interested in.

When they request their feeds, just get those out of memory.

Comment: So basically, I need to have an in-memory type database querying functionality. I could do this in LINQ with objects as I've done on my ecommerce stuff. Do you have a suggestion on specific implementation approaches? Your rep is too high to care for points it seems but I will put at least +50 to this.

Comment: @zipstory.com - Anything really. Just a `List<Feed>` and `List<City>` or whatever data structure you want to use. LINQ is about the right thing to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered cache-ing generic feeds, and tag them. And then per user, you just store reference to that tag/keyword.

Another possibility could be to store generic feed, and then filter on client. This will increase your bandwidth, but save cost on cache.

And if you are on HTML5, use Local Storage to hold user preference.